# Keras' ImageDataGenerator randomly throws an error when accessing image files

Tags: python, keras, python-imaging-library

I am using the keras.preprocessing.image ImageDataGenerator to stream images from a folder on my hard drive. It works mostly, but the code randomly throws an error when accessing images. The error message looks like this:

```
img = pil_image.open(path)
File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\envs\py35_cv2_nb_tf\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2452, in open
% (filename if filename else fp))
OSError: cannot identify image file 'd:/workspace/cat_dog/train\\cats\\666.jpg'
```

But I think it is misleading, since:

- sometimes it goes through the whole batch without any problem. When the crash occurs, it always happens at a different image.
- there is nothing obviously wrong with the cat666 image
- but after the crash, the file remains locked

Any ideas? I have already removed all meta-data from the images.

Comment: are you sure that given file path exists?

Answer (score 2):

You should use your path string variable as raw string, use **r** as prefix to evaluate the variable as raw string.

```
path = r'd:/workspace/cat_dog/train/cats666.jpg'
```

Comment: I actually do (without the r). No idea why the error message comes out like that. But the folder contains >10000 images and just sometimes this problem happens.

Comment: i have also worked with similar database with any such problem, from your question i guessed that PIL is parsing path string in wrong way.

Comment: I am working with Microsoft windows. After prefixing r and using the double escape (as windows wants) it worked